# List view reload when back pressed in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, fragmentmanager

I have Fragment XYZFragment where i display the list view.On the Listview item click i replace the Fragment like this.

```
Fragment fragment=new XYZFragment();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft= fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
```

But my problem is when i click back button the fragment reload the listview.It is never happen when i used to use Activity.
So my question is how to save the instance of previous fragment so that it will prevent the reloading of Data.

Comment: then reload your listView at onResume() of your fragment

Comment: Post the code that you have written for back button

Comment: try this ft.add(R.id.content_frame,fragment).commit();

Comment: Hi Imarn if i add the fragment then previous fragment list is also clicked in the visible fragment .

Comment: what exactly will happen when you clicked a listview items except for changing fragment??

Comment: On list view click item i am loading another fragment by replacing the old one i.e the content_frame.But when i back by pressing backbutton the listview loading again.

Answer (score 2):

without seeing your code we can't help you out but from your question i can figure out the problem, this solution may help you out.

create stack such that

```
private static Stack<Fragment> myFragStack;
myFragStack = new Stack<Fragment>();
```

//To Load the fragment

```
public void loadFragment(Fragment fragment){
 FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
 FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
 myFragStack.lastElement().onPause();
 ft.hide(myFragStack.lastElement());
 myFragStack.push(fragment);
}
```

//onBackPressed

```
public void onBackPressed() {
 FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
 FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

 if (myFragStack.size() > 1) {
    ft.remove(myFragStack.pop());
    myFragStack.lastElement().onResume();
    ft.show(myFragStack.lastElement());
    ft.commit();
 }
}
```

It's a sample code.. you can change it as per your requirement.
ft.replace() will completely remove the view & will lose the context so you can't maintain your list state, but using stacks maintaining fragments with hide-show will solve your problem.